# What is the most suitable method for implementing heavy graphix in windows?

Tags: c#, windows, graphics

hello i m using c# and suffering with delay problem. i want to change the technique for handling the graphics before this i want to know what will be the most efficient method for implementing heavy graphics,

i started making bmp files for each dynamic and static module and at the end i updates the whole GUI by pasting this bmps as layers after this i do double buffering but still not getting the required results i am thinking for using Direct-X ??

help required thanx in advance

Comment: i have a sort of simulator that displays the movement of flying objects on the globe that object may reach the 4000 limit each flying is a independent object i am currently doing calculation in a thread and displaying it after calculation completes i have maximum 10 sec to do all of this, my GUI is working good for 500 objects but after that it starts delay even this delay reaches to 5 sec that is very bad result i have to respond strictly in 10 sec in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft XNA](http://www.microsoft.com/XNA/) is a managed environment for doing extensive graphics. It's mainly used for Game development.

IMHO. Worth a look in your case.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to draw?  DirectX may be a good solution but it does depend on what you want to draw.

I've done some quite heavy updating of windows by doing the updates inside a thread.  Once the thread has finished doing its processing then the window gets updated.  This gives good results for my case (calculating and drawing a spectrogram that can be moved around).  It would, however, depend on how heavy what you want to draw is.